# What is meant by saying that two paths in $X$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$ are equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose that X is a topological space and $x_0$, $x_1$ are points of $X$. What is meant by saying that two paths in $X$ from $x_0$ to $x_1$ are equivalent?

I presume it's enough to just say the path is a continuous function $\sigma: [0,1] \rightarrow X $ such that $\sigma(0)=\sigma(1)$?

Comment: It probably means that they are homotopic (you can continuously deform one path into another, usually, fixing the start and end points). The definition you suggest for path is normally called a loop, a path is just a continuous map from $[0,1]$ into your space.

Comment: When one talks about equivalence of paths, one is usually constructing the fundamental group(oid), and the equivalence relation is "there is a homotopy between $f$ and $g$", keeping endpoints fixed.

Where are you learning about this?